# how to rearrange values in multiple cells in different columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a list of questions with 4 answer options for each question of them placed in 4 columns one next to the other, the correct answer option is ended with "!" which turn the cell to green as you can see in the image, I want to rearrange it in a way that shows the answer option cell in the first column. if you know how to do it please help me out! Thank you!
[Here is a sample of the spreadsheet I'm trying to edit](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vDyJUXZuVbzbfhSyMb8xmWdsl5Zm-OmC6pPF8sASwJk/edit?usp=sharing)[image: Screenshot of the sample]

Comment: You want to swap columns?

Comment: Still it's quit confusing,, plz [edit] your post & either reload the expanded view,, or share the file on cloud. Also show some expected results!

Comment: I have just updated my post and shared a link of a sample of the spreadsheet I'm trying to edit. I have also shown what the results I'm hoping to get. I hope that makes it a bit clearer to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a sorting combination of the following for each row,

1. Sort By Row (Left-to-Right sorting)
2. Sort On Cell Color

I've prepared a VBA solution that could be of help.

**NOTE**

1. This solution takes into consideration that the Green background-color formatting for the correct answer is already applied to the dataset.
2. You can change the RGB color codes in code below as needed

**VBA Code**

```
Sub sortLtoR_EachRow_ByCellColor()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng, rngSort, row_rngSort As Range
    Dim rngFirstCol_rngSort As Range
    Dim rowNumCurr_rngSort As Long
    Dim colsCount_rngSort As Long
    
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngSort = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select your range", Title:="SELECTION", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    Set rngFirstCol_rngSort = rngSort.Resize(, 1)
    colsCount_rngSort = rngSort.Columns.Count
    
    For Each rng In rngFirstCol_rngSort.Cells

        Set row_rngSort = rng.Resize(1, colsCount_rngSort)

        With ws.Sort

            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add(rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                SortOnValue.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142) 'change RGB values as needed
            .SetRange row_rngSort
            .Orientation = xlSortRows
            .Apply

        End With

    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Snapshots**

1. Range selection input box for left-to-right sort

[image: range_selection_inputBox]

2. You can find the RGB color codes as shown in the image below,

[image: rgb_colorCodes]

3. Result

[image: result_sorted_eachRow_LtoR]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much man, I can't thank you enough for this, I had 800 questions to sort out and I was going crazy because of it and you solved my problem, to those who might read this Question in the future and are absolutely beginners in Excel, you can use this link https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/ to help you along with @Karthick Ganesan answer and you will be all sorted!

Comment: Enjoy!  I'm glad it worked for you :)